# How to send displaytag's TableTagParameters from controller?

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, displaytag

We're using displaytag's display:table to show some results in our Spring MVC application.
This table is paginated and sorted by our own, sending POSTs to our controller, in which we're retrieving TableTagParameters to make the database query.
After redirecting to another page, we need to send these tableTagParameters in URL to show the table properly. I'm wondering if there's any chance to send these parameters out of the URL, with modelAndView.addObject or something like that?

Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

We have finally used the [PaginatedList](http://displaytag.sourceforge.net/11/displaytag/apidocs/org/displaytag/pagination/PaginatedList.html) interface of displaytag, which contains, besides of the list to be displayed, the page, the order and the column. More info at [displaytag docs](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/tut_externalSortAndPage.html)